# Is there a way to access DOM outside of documentElement <html>?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, comments

I have a script that searches a webpage for all comments and returns them in an array.

```
function getAllComments(rootElem) {
  var comments = [];
  var iterator = document.createNodeIterator(rootElem, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, filterNone, false);
  var curNode;
  while (curNode = iterator.nextNode()) {
    comments.push(curNode.nodeValue);
  }
  return comments;
}
```

I have it search for any comments within the `<html>` tag:

```
pre.textContent = getAllComments(document.documentElement);
```

However, there are sometimes comments outside the `<html>` tag, like on this site: http://brianmetcalf.com

Is there a way to target an element higher up the chain than `documentElement`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, answered my own question by accident — simply remove the selector:

`pre.textContent = getAllComments(document);`